# How to use Power App Search on a LookedUp column in a SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, sharepoint-list, powerapps-formula

I am currently builidng a PowerApp and I am struggeling with a simple search function. I connected the PowerApp to a SharePoint list (see image 1).

The SP-List **'Projekt'** consists out ouf:

Columns: Service |  Car  | Car_ID | Workitem

Type:    Text    | LookUp | LookUp  | LookUp

[SharePoint List][1]

I try to filter the text by using search. As long as I am using search on Service, everything works as expected. But if I use search on one of the other columns, the code returns an error, saying "Wrong Column Type. Expects text type" (Image 2)

```
Search('Projekt', "Item1", "Workitem")
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0NU5.png)

I assume it is due to the LookUp type, but I am not sure. Has anybody takled this problem and knows a workaround? Very happy for any suggestions

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I don't think this is going to work for you unless you change your underlying sharepoint list or use a collection.

The documentation on "Search" in powerapps say that **["the column must contain text.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup)**"

On most power platform applications, if you look into a Sharepoint list's lookup field or choice field, what you're actually looking at is called a "record," which is a single list that contains several items. Powerapps is expecting a string, but you're giving it a "record," so it's throwing an error.

I'd recommend you create a collection, and use that for what you're doing.

Try this:
ClearCollect(NewCollection, ShowColumns('Projekt', "WorkItem"));

Then, you should be able to do things like:

NewCollection.WorkItemColumn1.value ...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.

Now I am getting a new error saying that "Beahior function in a non-beahvior property. You cant use this property to change values elsewhere in the app."

This is probably because I wanted to use the ClearCollect function in a search bar for a BrowseGallary and change some data in an EditScreen
Seems like I have to change my data structure a little